# What are all these unnamed service principals in my Azure account?

Tags: azure, service-principal

When I run `az role assignment list --subscription $sub_id`, I get a list of ~20 service principals. All have `Contributor` access. Only 1 is named (the one I created). The others show `"principalName": "",`.

There is only 1 service principal showing in `AppRegistrations` in Azure portal.

Can someone help me understand what these SP's might be?

Comment: Answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201145/mysterious-users-in-azure-portal/71201201#71201201