# Mysterious users in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory

What are all these `Identity not found` "users" within my Azure Portal with Type of `Unknown`? Can I just delete them or...?

[image]

Comment: Looks like I had [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607576/what-are-all-these-unnamed-service-principals-in-my-azure-account) a long time ago when using `az role assignment list --subscription $sub_id`. I'm glad this has been answered. Thank you!